# Hibernate embeddable list mapping with identifier

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, hibernate-mapping

I have a Person entity with an embeddable Address and there's a one-to-many relation between them (a person can have multiple addresses). The current mapping is something like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {  
    // ... attributes
}

@Entity
public class Person {
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Person_addresses", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "personid")
    )
    /*
    Attribute ovverrides with annotations
    */
    private java.util.Set<Address> addresses = new java.util.HashSet<Address>();    
}
```

Using this annotation means that in the database I have a Person_addresses table which contains all the address attributes and a personid. But it also means that if I have a person with an address list and I update the address list, Hibernate deletes all the related records and inserts them (the modified ones) again.

As far as I know there's a way to have a primary key in this table for each record - in this case hibernate can decide which item of the list needs to be updated. So my question is, how can I map an embeddable list with identifiers in the joining table? (I hope it's understandable what I want:)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Primary_keys_in_CollectionTable

> The JPA 2.0 specification does not provide a way to define the Id in
>   the Embeddable. However, to delete or update a element of the
>   ElementCollection mapping, some unique key is normally required.
>   Otherwise, on every update the JPA provider would need to delete
>   everything from the CollectionTable for the Entity, and then insert
>   the values back. So, the JPA provider will most likely assume that the
>   combination of all of the fields in the Embeddable are unique, in
>   combination with the foreign key (JoinColumn(s)). This however could
>   be inefficient, or just not feasible if the Embeddable is big, or
>   complex. Some JPA providers may allow the Id to be specified in the
>   Embeddable, to resolve this issue. Note in this case the Id only needs
>   to be unique for the collection, not the table, as the foreign key is
>   included. Some may also allow the unique option on the CollectionTable
>   to be used for this. Otherwise, if your Embeddable is complex, you may
>   consider making it an Entity and use a OneToMany instead.

So thats it, it can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

As maestro's reply implies, the only portable solution is to convert this to use an entity and a one-to-many.

That said, Hibernate has a non-spec feature called an "id bag" which allows you to map a basic or embeddable collection with an identifier for each row, thereby giving you the efficient updates you want:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @CollectionId( columns={"address_id"}, type="int", generator="increment" )
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Person_addresses", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "personid"))
    private java.util.List<Address> addresses = new java.util.ArrayList<Address>(); 
}
```

Notice the switch from Set to List however.  Also notice the generated table structure... looks an awful lot like an entity ;)